# If $f(x)>0$, and $f''(x)\leq 0$ for $x>0$, show that $f'(x)\geq 0$ for $x>0$.

Tags: calculus

Assume on the contrary, $f'(x)\geq 0$, and since $f''(x)\leq 0$, then $f(x)$ is concave down and decreasing, so $f(x)$ will eventually less than $0$, contradict to $f(x)>0$, but how can I prove that $f(x)$ will eventually less than $0$ formally? thanks!

Comment: Suppose $f'(a) < 0$ for some $a > 0$. Define $g(x)$ in the following way. $g(x) = f(x)$ when $x \leq a$ and $g''(x) = 0$ when $x > a$. Then you can show that,

1) For sufficiently large $x$, $g(x) < 0$ (Hint: try explicitly writing $g(x)$ in terms of $f(a)$ when $x > a$).

2) $f(x) \leq g(x)$ so that $f(x) < 0$ when $x$ is sufficiently large.

Comment: Small mistake in the hint above: write $g(x)$ in terms of $f(a)$ and $f'(a)$, not just $f(a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $f'(a) <0$. Since $f'$ is non-increasing we get $f'(x) \leq f'(a)$ for all $x \geq a$. Hence $0 <f(x)=f(a)+\int_a^{x} f'(t)dt \leq f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$ for $x >a$. As $x \to \infty$ RHS tends to $-\infty$ leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Wow! Amazing Solution!

Comment: I am bit confused as if we take $f(x) = - (x-1)(x-2) $ when $x\in (1,2)$, then $f(x) $ doesn't satisfy the above in $(1,2)$. $f'(x) $ changes sign at $x=3/2$

Comment: I don't understand. First of all you have to take the domain as $(0,\infty)$; the fact that $f''(x) \leq 0$ on this entire domain is important for the proof.

Comment: Yeah yeah. Got it.